# phpunit Fatal error in calling assertDataSetsEqual

Tags: php, phpunit, dbunit

I am new to phpunit and kind of stuck in testing a database function with dbunit and getting the following error.

Fatal error: Cannot call constructor in C:\xampp\htdocs\testcases\PHPUnit\Extens
ions\Database\Constraint\DataSetIsEqual.php on line 41

My test function is as follows.

```
public function testNewAccountCreation()
    {
        $bank_account = new BankAccount('12345678912345678', $this->pdo);
        $bank_account->addAccount();

        $expected = $this->createMySQLXMLDataSet(dirname(__FILE__).'/_files/bank-account-after-new-account.xml');

        $actual = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_QueryDataSet($this->getConnection());
        $actual->addTable('bank_account');

        $this->assertDataSetsEqual($expected, $actual);
    }
```

I think the error is on calling assertDataSetsEqual function. Can any body please help me out with this problem on how to solve this error.

Thanks,
Furqan Ahmed.

Comment: Which of those lines is 41?

Comment: This is basically the test case that I have written line number 41 is basically the line of a file in phpunit framework class called DataSetIsEqual.php and it is basically the core file of the phpunit framework. I think upon calling $this->assertDataSetsEqual($expected, $actual); this error is raising, but have no idea how to resolve this error.